# Facebook Graph API user data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm aware of Facebook Graph API [Breaking Changes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/)

However, I didn't find anything there about removing the option to get user data by id, for example

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/100025807687946?fields=picture{url},id,name&access_token={user_token}
```

When I try this I get error type GraphMethodException

Was that also removed? I couldn't find any mention of this in the breaking changes article

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the ID from? Why not use /me?

Comment: I can get my info from the API but I used to get other people and it broke on my app... this is a random id of someone I got from Facebook

Comment: Your app is not supposed to access people’s info based on random IDs. Facebook introduced app-scoped user ids with API v2.0 already to prevent that. If you did not get an id the intended way via API in the first place, then your app has no business interacting with those profiles to begin with.

Comment: I think it was possiable to get info on a non app-scoped id, I guess they shut it down.